# Access: Not enough space on temporary disk error

Tags: ms-access

I am getting the following error:

"Not enough space on temporary disk. (Error 3183)"
"You tried to perform an operation that requires more space than is available on the temporary disk. Your temporary disk location is based on the TEMP DOS environment variable, which was set when your system started."

I am using Access 2007 as a front end. The database is on SQL Server 2008.
This happens when I am using a form which it's record source is a SQL query and am going to a specific record using the navigation control. The table has about half a million records.
I am on XP SP3 with 4GB RAM and there is 1 GB free.

Comment: Uh, sounds like you're out of disk space?

Comment: How much disk space is free on your system drive?

Comment: I assume the 1GB Free is your local hard drive. Two things... Can you show us the query? And are you perhaps out of space on the server?

Comment: I have 150 GB free HD disk space. Does access save the whole query locally, even if it is linked on SQL Server?

Comment: Jet/ACE caches the data it pulls down and it uses temp file space for certain kinds of operations (it's not really documented).

Comment: I am thinking of just using a SQL View and link to Access and just use that as the record source of the form.

Comment: In addition to the other answers (most likely the 2gig limit for the entire ACCESS database, regardless of how many tables / data is IN it).  It may also be due to a mistaken Cartesian join querying more records than you are expecting, thus multiplying the results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are most likely running into the 2GB limit on MS Access tables. Possibly in a temporary table being create/used during the query.

This is probably caused by whatever joins you have in your query, which tend to multiply the data. And with a million rows, all you have to do is multiple it by 2K of data per row to hit that limit)

You can solve this in a couple ways.

- You can move the biggest limiter in your where clause to the end (as I recall, the SQL is execute from the bottom up).
- You can simplify the query
- You could break the query up into subqueries, each which its own where clause, and then do a join on the results.

You might also be able to force the query to run on the SQL Server side; which I think happens by default but can be thwarted by an inefficient query (e.g., a calling a function that returns varchar in the where clause)

Comment: I think your answer is both correct and excellent, but it does leave the reader wondering a little bit why you would run into the 2GB table limitation when you're using SQL Server 2008. I think what you didn't explicitly explain is that the 2GB table limit is being reached during a query and why this is true.

Comment: The query is simple, just one table but one field is nvarchar(max) with some LEN (string length) as long as 40,000, with about 150,000 records.

Comment: The 2GB limit would be relevant if the problem is with Jet/ACE writing a temp file on the client workstation. That is, if Jet/ACE is pulling the data down from the SQL Server and writing it into a temp file, it will use a Jet/ACE temp file, and that will be subject to the 2GB size limit. Seems very unlikely, given the described scenario, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: Well... 40,000 * 150,000 is 6,000,000,000 - which would go over that 2GB limit. Perhaps you are doing something that is forcing all the data to come down at once. Can you show us the actual query.